# Segmentation fault when passing values to dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am working on an assignment that requires me to simulate Langton's ant.  I have dynamically allocated memory for a 2D array in the constructor of class Ant. The pointer to this array is a member of class Ant. Additionally, I have defined get functions for the rows and columns which I am using to pass these values to my array.

Ant.hpp

```
#ifndef ANT_HPP
#define ANT_HPP

enum Direction {UP, RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT};

class Ant
{
private:
char** board;
char spaceColor;
Direction facing;
int rows, cols, steps, stepNumber;
int startRow, startCol, tempCol, tempRow;
int lastRow, lastCol;
int thisRow, thisCol;

public:
Ant();
Ant(int, int, int, int, int);
void print();
void makeMove();
};
```

Ant.cpp

```
Ant::Ant()
{
rows = 5;
cols = 5;
steps = 5;
startRow = 0;
startCol = 0;
stepNumber = 0;
facing = LEFT;
setThisRow(5);
setThisCol(5);
setLastRow(5);
setLastCol(5);
setSpaceColor(' ');
board = new char*[rows];
for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
board[i] = new char[cols];
}
for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
board[i][j] = ' ';
}
}
board[startRow][startCol] = '*';
}

char Ant::getSpaceColor()
{
return spaceColor;
}

void Ant::makeMove()
{
if(getSpaceColor() == ' '){
board[getLastRow()][getLastCol()] = '#';
}
}

int Ant::getLastRow()
{
return lastRow;
}

int Ant::getLastCol()
{
return lastCol;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Ant.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
Ant myAnt;
myAnt.print();
myAnt.makeMove();
return 0;
}
```

Gdb has reported a segmentation fault at this line of code:

```
board[getLastRow()][getLastCol()] = '#';
```

Gdb is able to print accurate values for getLastRow() & getLastCol(), but cannot access memory for board[getLastRow()][getLastCol()].

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: We aren't sure either as you don't include the code for `getLastRow` etc

Comment: Variable `board` is not initialized to point to a properly allocated block of memory.

Comment: I'd suggest you stay away from char** and use simple std::vector. Address a cell by board[row_id*num_cols + col_id]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) by accessing array elements out of bounds. Your `setLastRow(5);` and 
`setLastCol(5);` functions cause both of your `getLastRow()` and `getLastCol()` functions to return the value of `5` but since arrays are **zero indexed** that would imply you are accessing `6th` element. So with:

```
board[getLastRow()][getLastCol()] = '#';
```

you are effectively calling:

```
board[5][5] = '#'; // undefined behavior because there are no 6 X 6 elements
```

whereas you can only have a maximum index of `4`:

```
board[4][4] = '#'; // OK as there are 5 X 5 elements
```

One solution is to have your functions return `lastRow - 1` and `lastCol - 1` respectively.

Comment: I have initialized the board pointer in the constructor for class Ant to point to an array of pointers, the problem persists however.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be what was causing the issue! Thank you very much, I was stumped on this for the past day

Answer (score 2):

Assuming board[getLastRow()][getLastCol()] translates to board[5][5], you go beyond the buffer. Your board is 0..4.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation fault usually refers that the program is accessing an unallocated address.

board[getLastRow()][getLastCol()]

You might want to check the starting index and ending index of the arrays.

- I think you might allocating the 2D array with index starting from 0
- getLastRow()/Col might return the size of the row / Col
- So when the index starts from 0, your last row index would be getLastRow()-1 and the same thing would apply for the Column

which yields ==> board[getLastRow()-1][getLastCol()-1]